# Right to left react-native

Tags: react-native, right-to-left

I'm using a RTL language, If I change the app into RTL and android device's language is English, the place of Icones in left for e.g turn to right . and If I change it into LTR and device's language is Arabic for instance, everything located in right turns to left. Is there anyway to fix the app so that everything is showed the same formation??
React-Native Version 0.42.0

Comment: you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52381831/6877799) to fix your problem.