# Right to left for specific text in react-native RTL

Tags: react-native, right-to-left, native-base

I am developing app in arabic in react native , i have used the tabs and menu from native base. i have aligned right because there is only single word . but now i have to write sentence which is right to left aligned. Is there way to set RTL format for specific text because when i set the `I18nManager.forceRTL(true);` it changed it for whole app and my previous work is all ruined and tabs not work correctly . please help .

Answer (score 20):

The `React Native` version is `0.57` now, And there is no react native configuration for `RTL` support yet.

But there is a native solution for it. for IOS and Android use below configuraion:

**IOS:**

search for `AppDeligete.m` file in your project path, then import `RCTI18nUtil` library from `React` and put RTL configuration inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` class. After putting my configs, you will have below code:

```
/* AppDeligete.m */
#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h> //<== AmerllicA config
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES]; //<== AmerllicA config
  [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES]; //<== AmerllicA config

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"rntest"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

**Android:**

search for `MainApplication.java` file in your project path, then import `I18nUtil` class from `com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager` and put RTL configuration inside `MainApplication` after `onCreate` function. After putting my configs, you will have below code:

```
/* MainAppliaction.java */

package com.rntest;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil; //<== AmerllicA config


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
                    new VectorIconsPackage()
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance(); //<== AmerllicA config
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this, true); //<== AmerllicA config
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true); //<== AmerllicA config

        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    }
}
```

Now rerun your react native stacks. these configurations need to restart the development process. After the restart, the project is ready for RTL, for my project all `FlexBox` behavior change to `right to left`. I repeat it, *ALL OF BEHAVIOR*.

*NOTE*: In **Android**, all of `react native` components will change to `RTL` direction but in **IOS** for the right to left direction of `react native` `Text` component, use `writingDirection: 'rtl'` style code.

*ATTENTION*: Using `textAlign: 'right/left/center'` is a different concept The `RTL/LTR` direction.

Comment: Best answer for forcing RTL, love it

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to apply rtl to some but not all text, you should replace that line of code with
`I18nManager.allowRTL(true);`

Then add textAlign: "right" to the text you want to align

Answer (score 0):

Also `alignSelf: 'flex-start'|'flex-end'` can be used to place `Text` components properly while switching between `rtl`/`ltr` directions.