# How to set direction property of a View to RTL in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to set direction property of a `View` in react-native ... something like:

`<View direction="rtl" />`

**OR**

How to force the direction of the whole app to be Right-To-Left ... regardless of the current Device-Language after [making my app RTL Ready](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#making-an-app-rtl-ready)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737059/right-to-left-for-specific-text-in-react-native-rtl maybe this will help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by calling `forceRTL` in MainApplication.java like:

**MainApplication.java**
    import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this,true);
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true);
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<Application
...
android:supportsRtl="true"
...
/>
```

cause calling forceRTL in `App.js` does require the app to be restarted to work.

`I18nManager.forceRTL(true); // Work on second-load of the app`

Now when I set `flexDirection: 'row'` it will be right-to-left

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply use `flex-direction`. Please see following code snippet

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: language === ARABIC_LANGUAGE ? 'row-reverse' : 'row' }}/>
```

Comment: if the device-lang is RTL (Arabic for example) ... `row-reverse` for the app will be left-to-right ... we don't want that ... but thank u for your help anyway :)

Comment: Have u tested it ? I have it in front of my eyes :D in both emulator and physical-device ... and that's exactly what the docs states here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps

Comment: please see this. https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-allen-7f0nh?fontsize=14

Comment: thank u for trying to help ... but I'm saying that ... if the **Device language is set to Arabic through Settings** ... `row` will be right-to-left ... and it makes alot of sense :)

Comment: Be careful!, Properties like `marginStart` won't behave as expected

Answer (score 2):

Add '\u{200F}' in front of text to change direction to rtl.

```
_rtlcheck =  (language, data) => {

            if (rtlLanguages.includes(language)) {
                return '\u{200F}' + data
            }else{
                return data
            }
    };
```

Comment: Kind of a dirty weird hack I'm not gonna use it, but I liked your creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Import this in AppDelegate.m :

`#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>`

Add this library: `react-native-restart`

And simply use it like this in your component ->

```
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";
import RNRestart from "react-native-restart";

I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
RNRestart.Restart();
```

Updating components based on RTL ->

```
const isRTL = I18nManager.isRTL;

Flip Text : textAlign: "left"

Flip TextInput : textAlign: isRTL ? "right" : "left"

Flip Icon / Image : transform: [{ scaleX: isRTL ? -1 : 1 }]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below library. it supports RTL for react native and also localization

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-i18n

Hope it will work.

Comment: My app doesn't want localization-support ... it should be RTL all the way .. but thank u for taking the time to help :)