# react native and Arabic Text in justify mode

Tags: react-native, arabic, arabic-support, text-justify

I'm trying to make an screen with Arabic text in it. It is basically a big  that include smaller  components nested into it. (the container  is like the page, while the smaller ones are parts that need their own even handling onPress...etc).
I want to make the text shown in justified way with lines starting/ending uniformly. So I went to the parent and added this style:
textContainer: {
direction: "rtl",
textAlign: "justify",
},
and it works really fine except the last line, it starts from the left instead of the right. So, is there a way to tell the  to justify and also make the last line start from right?
Here is how it looks(https://pasteboard.co/JMDRj1e.png)
if you look at the last line it starts from left and not from right, I think this is a bug in react native.

Comment: were you able to resolve it? I have got the same issue

Comment: no luck so far :(

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me,
For iOS, I gave the text style `writingDirection: 'rtl'` and by importing #import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h> in AppDelegate.m, added these two lines in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ,

```
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:TRUE];
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:TRUE];
```

and for android you can refer here, [How to set direction property of a View to RTL in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319997/how-to-set-direction-property-of-a-view-to-rtl-in-react-native). Also, you need to add `transform: [{scaleX: -1}]` and `flexDirection: row-reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation will only align the first line. in order to align an Arabic paragraph / or more than one line, you can do the following:

import I18nManager from react native in your app.js

`import { I18nManager } from "react-native";`

then add this line below the import to allow RTL

`I18nManager.allowRTL(true);`

finnaly you can add  `writingDirection: "rtl"` to the style of the arabic text and it should be aligned the correct way