# Use text-align-last in react native

Tags: css, react-native, styling, text-styling

I want to justify my text and align right the last line.
Here is what I tried:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

const Content1 = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>
        سواد رسانه‌ای یکی از انواع سواد هاست که بیشتر با سوادهای بصری و تحلیلی و
        اینترنتی در ارتباط است. با ایجاد و گسترش رسانه‌های سمعی و بصری، این
        مفهوم به وجود آمد و با گسترش شبکه‌های اجتماعی، دارای مفاهیم و ابعاد
        گسترده‌تر و پیچیده تری شد. یک نوع درک متکی بر مهارت است که می‌توان
        براساس آن انواع رسانه‌ها را از یکدیگر تمیز داد، انواع تولیدات رسانه‌ای
        را از یکدیگر تفکیک و شناسایی کرد. همچنین سواد رسانه‌ای آمیزه‌ای از
        تکنیک‌های بهره‌وری مؤثر از رسانه‌ها و کسب بینش و درک برای تشخیص رسانه‌ها
        از یکدیگر است. توانایی دسترسی، تحلیل، ارزیابی، و خلق پیام در شکل‌های
        گوناگون (چاپی، صوتی، فیلم/ویدیویی، اینترنتی، …) بر پایهٔ درک آگاهانه و
        انتقادی از ماهیت رسانه‌های جمعی، فنونی که از سوی تولیدکنندگان رسانه مورد
        استفاده قرار می‌گیرد، و تأثیر این فنون بر فرد و جامعه. سواد رسانه‌ای به
        مثابه یک حوزه بین‌رشته‌ای، به واکنش لازم به محیط ارتباط الکترونیکی
        پیچیده، فراگیر، و دائم‌التغییر سده ۲۱ تبدیل شده‌است. تعریف خلاصه:فهم و
        تحلیل تمام مفاهیم و مطالبی که از رسانه می‌گیریم. به‌طور خیلی ساده سواد
        رسانه ای در حوزه اخبار یعنی ابتدا تفکر و تحلیل خبر و جستجو در مورد درستی
        و نادرستی خبر و سپس انتشار آن و چنانچه نتوان در مورد منبع خبر مطمئن شد
        از انتشار خبر خودداری کرد. همچنین واژه‌هایی همچون سوادمند رسانه ای ایجاد
        شده‌اند و بر این باور هستند که سوادمند، به شخصی گفته می‌شود که چند سواد
        را، توامان دارد.
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  descriptionText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    direction: 'rtl',
    textAlign: 'justify',
    padding: '5%',
  },
});
```

But didn't worked.
how can I use text-align-last in react-native to solve my problem?

Comment: give full width to the descriptionText container. and share the full code so I can help

Comment: I added the full code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737059/right-to-left-for-specific-text-in-react-native-rtl  have a look.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#making-an-app-rtl-ready